# Верно ли выделена запятыми часть "и не прошло и мгновения"?

Tags: запятые

*Ведь в один прекраснейший день я спасла черную кошку с дерева, и не прошло и мгновения, как на меня упало то самое дерево.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запятая перед "как" нужна, она отделяет придаточное предложения от главного. Перед И я бы не стал ставить запятую из-за слова "ведь", которое вроде бы относится ко всему предложению, то есть является общим второстепенным членом предложения.

Comment: Благодарю. Не могу различить, когда придаточные части нужно отделять запятыми, а когда они относятся к чему-то общему.

Comment: Придаточное в любом отделяется, если только это действительно придаточное, а не фразеологизм с "как" или другим союзом. Тут о другом речь: если бы не было общего члена и "вдруг" относилось бы только к первой части, тогда было бы ССП и запятая перед И разбивала его на две части. Но ведь довод к предыдущему, вводимый словом "ведь", относится и к падению дерева, правильно я понимаю? Контекста просто не хватает. То есть его факт должен пояснять мысль, высказанную ранее.

Answer (score 2):

Помимо искажённого стандартного выражения "в один прекрасный день", просматриваются такие речевые проблемы.

1. Что такое "*спасти с дерева*"? Можно спасти *кого-то **от** чего-то*. **С** чего-то или **из** чего-то *конкретно* снимают или вытаскивают (напр. бегемота из болота). Возможный вариант: "спасла, *сняв* с дерева".
2. В один прекрасный **день** я сделала нечто (обычно требующее времени), но не прошло и **мгновения**...
   "Мгновения" не сочетаются ни с *днём*, ни с действием, момент *окончания* которого **не обозначен**. 
   Как можно отсчитывать "мгновение" от завершения операции спасения?
3. Описываемая ситуация *нереалистична*: речь идёт о кошке (т. е. взрослом животном), которая обычно не нуждается в "спасении". Спасать можно *котёнка*, которого кошка-мама ещё не научила правильно спускаться (хвостом вперёд). Если закрыть на это глаза (видимо, это было "аварийное" дерево, готовое упасть), то всё равно изменить нужно многое.

> Ведь в один прекрасный день я спасла черную кошку, сняв её с дерева, и
>   едва я с ней спустилась, как то самое дерево на меня же и упало.

Answer (score 1):

Не нравится мне это предложение — Вы уж извините. Какое-то оно искусственное: суть понятна, а скомпоновано вроде и не по-русски.

*В один прекраснейший день*. Так обычно говорят, когда день действительно был наипрекраснейшим (а ведь это не Ваш случай). В ироничном смысле лучше использовать фразу *в один прекрасный день.*

*Я спасла черную кошку с дерева*. Кошка с дерева — возникает ощущение, что черное животное обитало/жило на дереве, а Вы его от чего-то или кого-то спасли (от пожара? от хищной птицы?). А ведь важно, что кошка черная, а не с дерева (если я правильно понимаю).

Думаю, предпочтительнее написать так: *я спасла* (откуда?) *с дерева черную кошку*.
(*Два дня понадобилось волонтерам, чтобы спасти с дерева кота — десантника и бойца.*)

*И не прошло и мгновения...* Первый союз "и" я бы заменила на "но".

У меня получилось такое предложение.
Ведь в один прекрасный день я спасла с дерева черную кошку, но не прошло и мгновения, как на меня то самое дерево и упало.

Comment: Слава богу не я автор этого предложения, можете не извиняться) И перестраивать его я не в праве.